# how to play animation on loading element inner html?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to play some animations when loading element's innerHTML, here is my code:

```
function loadslide(){

        ...
        $('.m').html($('.bigSlider div:nth-child(1)').html()).fadeIn("slow");
}

$('.rightarrow').click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        loadslide();
});
```

but no animation is shown when I click the button.

Comment: What does the developer console say?

Comment: Don't remove the code that may be useful. You have an `m` variable that doesn't defined in anywhere. Show us the entire related code, and the HTML

Comment: Is the click event fired ?

Comment: @lateek35 yes, and there are no errors

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude see the edit

Comment: The edit is a hardcode here, not the real code that you have. HTML is not shared anyway. I can't help you with a crystal ball. Wait, I can, but I don't want to imagine things, if it's as simple as you publish all related code.If I have a head pain and I tell to a doctor by phone "I have a pain in the head" but don't explain better and doctor can't see me, doctor throws me to the fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, the element needs to be hidden for it to be able to fadeIn

So you'll have to arrange your element accordingly, if there's nothing showing for your element simply

```
 $('.m').hide().html($('.bigSlider div:nth-child(1)').html()).fadeIn("slow");
```

If that can't be done because it has some visible parts maybe you can have an inner div with nothing on it, so you can hide it. But it **needs** to be hidden beforehand